# issue while using AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

After making some gradle updates, Android started giving me errors related to version number so in the process of fixing them I encountered issues related to RXJava, I am using retrofit in my project.

**the error I am getting is.**

```
observeOn(io.reactivex.Schedulers) in Observable cannot be applied to (rx.Scheduler)
```

**code** 
ManEmpAct.java

```
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.dopay.onboarding.Constants;
import com.dopay.onboarding.DoPayApplication;
import com.dopay.onboarding.R;
import com.dopay.onboarding.data.AppPreferences;
import com.dopay.onboarding.enums.StartStopAppMonitor;
import com.dopay.onboarding.fragment.CreateEmployeeDetailsFragment;
import com.dopay.onboarding.fragment.EmployeeEditFragment;
import com.dopay.onboarding.modules.UserAccountManagementView;
import com.dopay.onboarding.refactor_fragments.CountryByPhoneNumberFragment;
import com.dopay.onboarding.refactor_fragments.TakePhotoFragment;
import com.dopay.onboarding.refactor_fragments.TakePhotoFragmentCamera2;
import com.dopay.onboarding.refactor_fragments.ViewImageFragment;
import com.dopay.onboarding.util.DialogUtil;
import com.dopay.onboarding.util.EventsTracker;
import com.dopay.onboarding.util.UIUtil;

//import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;

import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
compositeSubscription.add(publishRelay.asObservable().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(iView -> {

}
```

the full list of dependencies used in the app, just in case I am not picking up the right one
**build.gradle**

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 26

    dependencies {

    //DEPENDENCIES RELATED TO RETROFIT, RXJAVA, RXANDROID
    implementation 'com.jenzz.appstate:adapter-rxjava2:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.laimiux.rxnetwork:rxnetwork:0.0.4'
    //Retrofit, RxJava and OkHttp,Gson,Dagger,ButterKnife.
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava2', version: '2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.1.0'
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jenzz.appstate:appstate:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'    
    implementation 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.21buttons:fragment-test-rule:1.0.0'    
    implementation 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.1.0'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.9.0'
    implementation ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    annotationProcessor ('com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'    
    implementation 'com.futuremind.recyclerfastscroll:fastscroll:0.2.5'    
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'    
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.fafaldo:fab-toolbar:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:8.1.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.5'    
    implementation group: 'com.joooonho', name: 'selectableroundedimageview', version: '1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    //releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.1'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.5.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-base:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.5.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-testng:1.6.4'

}
```

**gradle version**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Unable to figure out where the issue is, could you please share some info on what I might be doing wrong

Thanks
R

Comment: post all of your import statements

Comment: What is the type of publishRelay ?

Comment: @SantanuSur I have updated my imports used in that java file

Comment: BehaviorRelay publishRelay = BehaviorRelay.create("default");

Comment: please check wether the observable returned by `publishRelay`

Comment: First use a variable to store the `observable` and check the import statement !

Comment: @SantanuSur I donot quite understand, can you give me a sample code of what you want me to check

Comment: @SantanuSur  when I did this. Observable  abcd = publishRelay.asObservable();
I got incompatable types, that is what you wanted me to try?
required io.reactivex.observable but found rx.observable

Comment: I have seen that imports in BehaviourRelay is using import com.jakewharton.rxrelay.RelaySubscriptionManager.RelayObserver;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.annotations.Beta;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite;

Comment: i am using implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0', changed it to implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.1.0' will compile and check.
if you think of anything else please let me know @SantanuSur

Comment: I have two dependencies
  implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.1.0'
and the code is using  rxrelay:rxrelay:1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing rxjava 2 with rxjava 1 schedulers. Probably rxrelay is pulling rxjava one and you can import the schedulers from there accidentally - I haven't confirmed this, but if so you could simply migrate to a more recent rxrelay version. Check the [readme](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/blob/master/README.md) for more details. Also mind that this might be any other library and not specifically rxrelay.

In any case, as you can see from the full path in the error it states that
`rx.Scheduler` (rxjava1 scheduler) cannot be used as a parameter to a method that expects `io.reactivex.Schedulers` (rxjava2 scheduler)

I would highly advise to update all libraries to rxjava2 so you won't find this issue again.